# Ruby ERB class gives "undefined local variable or method", but erb parses fine

Tags: ruby, erb

With this ERB template in a file *test.erb*:

```
% for i in 0..1
  foo<%=i%>;
% end
```

erb parses it as expected:

```
$ erb test.erb
    foo0;
    foo1;
```

Trying to use Ruby's ERB class as follows, in *test.rb*:

```
require 'erb'

e = ERB.new(File.read("test.erb"))
File.open("test.out", 'w') do |f|
    f.write e.result(binding)
end
```

Gives:

```
$ ruby test.rb
(erb):2:in `block in <main>': undefined local variable or method `i' for main:Object (NameError)
        from <...>/lib/ruby/1.9.1/erb.rb:838:in `eval'
        from <...>/lib/ruby/1.9.1/erb.rb:838:in `result'
        from test.rb:5:in `block in <main>'
        from test.rb:4:in `open'
        from test.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

and in a more recent Ruby version:

```
$ ruby test.rb
Traceback (most recent call last):
        5: from test.rb:4:in `<main>'
        4: from test.rb:4:in `open'
        3: from test.rb:5:in `block in <main>'
        2: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/erb.rb:905:in `result'
        1: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/erb.rb:905:in `eval'
(erb):2:in `block in <main>': undefined local variable or method `i' for main:Object (NameError)
```

Any ideas gratefully received! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use syntax like `% some code` in ERB you need to pass `trim_mode: '%'` when you initialize ERB. Like this:

```
ERB.new(File.read("test.erb"), trim_mode: "%")
```

Other possible options for initialization are described [here](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html#method-c-new).

Or, alternatively, you can keep your ERB initializer as it is and instead change your ERB code to

```
<% for i in 0..1 %>
  foo<%=i%>;
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yep.  The default handling for `%` lines is different between the `erb` command and the `ERB` class.  You would get the same `undefined local variable` if you were to run `erb -P test.erb`.  The `-P` option disables evaluation of `%`, making it similar to the `ERB` default.

Comment: Thanks both! :)That trim_mode flag appears to have arrived after v2.3, but is present in v2.7.